# Pharo SubscriptOutOfBounds:5 error

Tags: debugging, smalltalk, pharo

I have a Pharo extension that adds promises to Pharo Smalltalk. I then use the promise extension to do a bank transfer with the following bank application.An account contacts the bank in order to transfer money to another account. This code fails with the error **SubscriptOutOfBounds:5**. I looked at [Recursive method in pharo produces #SubscriptOutOfBounds:8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619649/recursive-method-in-pharo-produces-subscriptoutofbounds8). It talks about array bounds but I have no clue where I could be using arrays in my implementation unless the stack does.The debugger says something about arrays but at the moment it is too cryptic for me.The promises work just fine with other examples but fail for this particular example. And it appears the error occurs due to the commented out code in Account>>transfer:to:

Below is Account>>transfer:to:

```
transfer: amount to: account
        | bank promise|
        bank := Bank new.
        (availability > (lowerLimit + amount)) ifTrue: [    availability := availability - amount.
        promise := [ bank transfer: amount from: self to: account ]promiseValue. 
        "promise
            then: [ :respose | 
                respose
                    ifTrue: [ self reduceBalance: amount ] ]
            catch: [ :error | ^error ] "]
            ifFalse: [ ^ self ].
```

And this is Bank >> transfer:amount:from: to:

```
transfer: amount from: anAccount1 to: anAccount2
    |transfered|
    transfered := false.
    (anAccount1 availableBalance < anAccount1 lowerLimit + amount)
     ifTrue: 
    [self error: 'Account lower Limit reached', (anAccount1 lowerLimit) printString ] 
    ifFalse:
    [ self deposit: amount to: anAccount2. transfered := true ].
    ^transfered
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: The error happens when you try to access a `SquenceableCollection` (e.g., an `Array`) with an invalid index. Since there is no such an object in the code your question shows, I presume that the failure must be happening in `reduceBalance:` or `deposit:to:`. The debugger should make that clear. It is just a matter of becoming familiar with it.

Comment: This is some feedback I have just received, "If you fork during your promise you lose context because what you execute in the future is probably in another process." This seems like the most accurate cause of the problem since promise>> then: catch: seems to be causing the exception. How can I use the promise in my Account>>transfer:to:  (or any other method) without the SubscriptOutOfBounds: error?

Comment: With due respect, may I suggest you to becoming more familiar with Smalltalk before trying to implement promises? Don't take me wrong, I admire your enthusiasm. It is just that the journey will evolve more naturally.

Comment: Thank you. Took your advice and eventually figured out that the Account>>transfer:to: ought to have been checking ifNotNil: instead of ifNotTrue since on success, the promise returns a bank object. I believe I was and still not adept at SmallTalk.

Comment: Excellent. Note also that a good practice for this site is to write the answer yourself if you managed to address the problem.